# how to remove file extension from file name when hit the url in php?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am working with [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/). This is my filename ("localhost/blogs.php")
but I want to call this "blog.php" file as ("localhost/blogs"). How can I remove the file extension from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an apache server the easiest way is to use mod_rewrites
Create a .htaccess file and write the following code:

```
   # Options
   Options -Multiviews
   Options +FollowSymLinks

   #Enable mod rewrite
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^blog$ blog.php [QSA,L]
```

This will mean when /blog is added in the browser then the server will call blog.php

Comment: this is code is not working.......i have different files with different names, can u help me that how to remove .php extension

Comment: create a new file in the root, localhosst/.htaccess, save it as .htaccess as filetype text, no file extension. 

Make sure you are using an apache server. And then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a PHP issue but a mod_rewrite one. Enable mod_rewrite in Apache (probably already the case) and then add a file named .htaccess in your website's root directory and add this content to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I edited the answer, try it with that. Also please be more clear as to what's going wrong (what errors,what do you see on the screen etc.)

Answer (score 0):

PHP frameworks use this kind of thing, I can advice codeIgniter.

Otherwise you need to create a URL handler, and use a .htacces file

[This](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/) might help